# Injecting into nested DOM elements created with template literals

Tags: javascript, dom, append, appendchild

I have a fairly simple question. I need to create a list of items that is quite deeply nested, something of this sort (in reality every div has like 20+ classes, data-attributes and so forth):

```
<div class="one" data-foo="a x y z">
  <div class="two" data-bar="x y z">
    <ul class="three" data-foobar="a b c">
    // contents
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

My current code is:

```
    const div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.classList.add("one", all the other classes);
    div1.setAttribute("data-foo", "lots of data attributes");
    
    const div2 = document.createElement("div");
    div2.classList.add("two", all the other classes);
    div2.setAttribute("data-bar", "lots of data attributes");
    
    const div3 = document.createElement("div");
    div3.classList.add("three", all the other classes);
    div3.setAttribute("data-foobar", "lots of data attributes");

    div1.appendChild(div2);
    div2.appendChild(div3);

    // getting items for the list & other code

    div3.appendChild(someOutputData);
```

I came up with a great idea of using a template literal so I don't have to add all the extra properties, classes etc. I know it seems like I could've fixed it with simple `foreach` but there are bazillion of other things like aria tags etc. etc.

So my old code becomes:

```
 const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
 const layout = `<div class="one" data-foo="a x y z">
   <div class="two" data-bar="x y z">
     <ul class="three" data-foobar="a b c">
        
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>`;

wrapper.innerHTML = layout;
wrapper.appendChild(someOutputData);
```

Million times clearer, right?

The problem is `wrapper.appendChild(someOutputData);` is not longer injecting data into `.three` but into `<div>` wrapper that is above `.one`.

Is there some way I can target nested DOM elements created via template literals? How can I push my `someOutputData` (list of nodes) into `.three` using the second snippet? Also can I omit wrapper somehow? I don't really need the "div" around my list.

Comment: So why are you not using variables?

Comment: I know I could use {content} within `.three` and then pass it to a function but still I won't be able to append properly or am I wrong?

Comment: You would have to select the element you just created.... You are appending to the  div, not the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So use variables in your template and select the element you created to append the elements

```js
function createComponent(data1, data2, data3, listData) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  const layout = `<div class="one" data-foo="${data1}">
    <div class="two" data-bar="${data2}">
      <ul class="three" data-foobar="${data3}">
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>`;

  wrapper.innerHTML = layout;
  wrapper.querySelector("ul").append(...listData);

  return wrapper;
}


const makeLi = (text) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text;
  return li;
};

const lis = ['foo', 'bar'].map(makeLi);
const elem = createComponent(1,2,3, lis);
document.body.append(elem);


const lis2 = [1,2,3,4,5].map(makeLi);
const elem2 = createComponent(1,2,3, lis2);
document.body.append(elem2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit unclear what you mean.

Perhaps this using map and join?

```js
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = ["a","b","c","d"]
  .map(text => `<div class="one" data-foo="a x y z">
   <div class="two" data-bar="x y z">
     <ul class="three" data-foobar="a b c">
        <li>${text}</li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </div>`).join("");
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```